# Visual Basic 6.0 - Need to enable/disable Scrollbar of MDI form in runtime

Tags: vb6, runtime, scrollbar, mdi

I need to enable the MDI parent scroll bar only in some MDI child forms and disable it for other forms. I have resize code for resolution changes but for DPI changes the forms width goes beyond screen size. So I need to enable it for these forms and disable it for other forms.

For Resolution

```
ResizeX = Screen.Width / (1024 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX)
ResizeY = Screen.Height / (768 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY)
```

For DPI

```
XPIXELSPERINCH = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, 88)
YPIXELSPERINCH = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, 90)
```

Is there any way of using sendmessage function to disable / enable the MDI parent form scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little bit with `ShowScrollBar()` and `SetWindowLong()`.  I was unsuccessful in both, as VB6 takes over and keeps re-creating the scrollbars.

What I did manage to do, which has its own issues.  I'm sure you can come up with other "hacks" to get around that issue.

Anyway, set the `frmMdiChild`'s `MDIChild`'s property is set to `False` and set things up like so:

```
Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Const GW_CHILD As Long = 5
```

Then when you when you're loading the form:

```
SetParent frmMdiChild.hwnd, GetWindow(frmMdiParent.hwnd, GW_CHILD)
```

This will place the child within the window.  You might have to relocate it.  And as I mentioned, if the user resizes `frmMdiParent`, you'll need to likely adapt it somehow.

Now, if you simply call the following instead (not getting the proper child):

```
SetParent frmMdiChild.hwnd, frmMdiParent.hwnd
```

You'll get around the issue completely.  But you may not be satisfied with the way it looks.  If you are, then perfect!